# Using .find function to find size between character and another character in c++

Tags: c++, date, find, size

I am looking for some help with a find function in C++. I have searched and searched but nothing I try works correctly.

The question is:

> The function has to convert this date to the international format. For example: If the string "December 29, 1953" is received, the string that the function should return must be "29 December 1953".

I seem to understand what is needed to solve the entire problem, but I am getting stuck with starting the new `.find` function from the start of the date to the comma. My code seems to still be finding the position of the comma from the start of the string and not from the first char after the space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
string convertDate(string dateP){
    int sizeOfString = dateP.size();
    int space = dateP.find(' ');
    space = space + 1;
    int comma = dateP.find(',', space);
    
    dateP = dateP.substr(space, comma);

    return dateP;
}

int main(){

    string date;

    cout << "Enter the date: " << endl;
    getline(cin, date, '\n');

    string newDate = convertDate(date);

    cout << endl;
    cout << newDate;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you used `std::istringstream`, the solution becomes trivial, without all of the searches for spaces, commas, and calls to `substr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have searched and searched but nothing I try works correctly.

Well, if you're looking for a solution to the problem, and willing to use something you haven't tried, then usage of [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) makes the code trivial:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string convertDate(std::string dateP)
{
   // create a stream from the passed-in string
   std::istringstream strm(dateP);

   // get the month, day and year from the stream
   std::string month, day, year;
   strm >> month >> day >> year;

   // get rid of the comma (the last character in the day string)
   day.pop_back();

   // put together the resulting string and return
   return day + " " + month + " " + year;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << convertDate("December 29, 1953");
}
```

Output:

```
29 December 1953
```

Note the lack of code to search for spaces, or creation of substrings.

The `std::istringstream` automatically knows how to skip whitespace, similar to `std::cin`, so no code is required to search for spaces.

The `pop.back()` function removes the last item in a string.  Since the `','` is assumed to be the last character in the `day` string, `pop.back()` simply removes it.

At the end, we just paste together all the pieces and return the resulting string.

Comment: Thanks again for your help @Paul! I really appreciate it

Comment: Instead of using `day.pop_back()` to ignore the comma after reading it, you could simply skip it when reading `day` from the `strm` to begin with, eg: `strm >> month; std::getline(strm >> std::ws, day, ','); strm >> year;`

Comment: FYI, it is not the `std::istringstream` (or `std::cin`) that skips whitespace, it is `operator>>` itself that handles that, for ALL types of streams.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like `convertDate(string americanDate)` instead of `convertDate(string dateP)`, then:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string convertDate(string americanDate)
{
    int blank = americanDate.find(" ");
    string month = americanDate.substr(0, blank);
    int comma = americanDate.find(",");
    string day = americanDate.substr(blank+1, comma-blank-1);
    string year = americanDate.substr(comma+2, americanDate.size());
    string date = day+ " "+ month + " " + year;
    return date;
}

int main()
{
    string americanDate;
    cout <<"Enter the date: ";
    getline(cin,americanDate);
    string newDate = convertDate(americanDate);
    cout << newDate;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Geno!